# Yii2 first and last items in the ListView

Tags: php, listview, yii2

I have a typical ListView widget in a view as follows:

```
public function actionView($id)         
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => \app\models\Verses::find()->where(['sura_id' =>$id])->with('sura')]);          
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

In the view a list of `Verses` model is rendered and the pager of the ListView is available too.

I want to add some details to the page title. Those details are data from the first and last records of the `Verses` model rendered in the list.

I have tried to use `min()` and `max()` PHP functions to get the first and the last records in the view as follows:

```
$min = min($model->verses);
echo $min->verse_id;
```

However, it returns the ultimate first record regarding-less the current pager page. In other words, it does not return the `verse_id` value of the first item of the list.

Is there any way to get the first, last or even a specific nth item of the ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
$first = reset($models);
$last = end($models);
```

Read more about [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) and [`end`](http://php.net/end).

Answer (score 1):

You could access to the models array of dataProvider a get the firts and the last

```
public function actionView($id)         
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => \app\models\Verses::find()->where(['sura_id' =>$id])->with('sura')]);  


        $first = $dataProvider['models'][0];
        $last =  $dataProvider['models'][$dataProvide['totalCount']-1];
```

or you can use

```
        $myModels = $dataProvider->getModels();
        $first = myModels[0];
        $last =  myModels[$dataProvide['totalCount']-1];
```

and for the page you can use count instead of total count

```
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful, but in paging, `getTotalCount()` should be replaced by `getCount()` and the model is gotten by `getModels()` as the following: `$s = $dataProvider->getModels();
$start = $s[0]->verse_id;
$end = $dataProvider->getCount()-1+$start;`.

[**Refrence**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html)

Comment: `totalCount` will return the total count of the model's records, regarding-less the current page. Using `getCount` is correct here.